# Spring web application - getting form data - post method

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I`m trying to get from Form parameter to a DTO object, i clicked on the button but nothing happaning, and it seems that the data isnt transfer

why is that?

Cntroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scanRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String scanRequest(@ModelAttribute("scanForm")UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "home";
    }

    model.addAttribute("msg", userRequestDTO.getSellerName());


    return "home";
}
```

DTO:

```
public class UserRequestDTO {

    private String seller_name;

    public String getSellerName() {
        return seller_name;
    }

    public void setSellerName(String sellerName) {
        seller_name = sellerName;
    }
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/requestlist" modelAttribute="scanForm" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>
    <spring:bind path="seller_name">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="text" path="seller_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Seller Name" autofocus="true"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="seller_name"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

**Update Error:**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'scanForm' available as request attribute

**Update Error - 2**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'seller_name' of bean class
>   [com.searcher.model.UserRequestDTO]: Bean property 'seller_name' is
>   not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of
>   the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your post entry point is `/scanRequest` but your submitting to `/requestlist`, it fails cause you are not targeting the right mapped method .

if `/requestlist` is the request Mapping of your controller (the one who contains the method scanRequest) than change your form to :

```
<form:form method="POST" 
action="${contextPath}/requestlist/scanRequest" 
modelAttribute="scanForm"  class="form-signin">...
```

if is is not and your controller do

```
   <form:form method="POST" 
    action="${contextPath}/scanRequest" 
    modelAttribute="scanForm"  class="form-signin">...
```

**EDIT:**

Your `scanForm` is not present when rendering the page containing the form, so you have to add it, add this method to your controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("scanForm")
public UserRequestDTO getScanForm(){
  return new UserRequestDTO();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

add a correct getter to your model :

```
public String getSellerName() {
        return seller_name;
    }
```

this is not a proper getter for attribute `seller_name` change it to

```
public String getSeller_name() {
    return seller_name;
}
```

**or** let your IDE generate them automatically.

Comment: You right, after i change it it throw me an error (i added it to my question)

Comment: @Guyb check my edit , dude your getter is wrong, the convention is get+firtLetterto uppercase+the rest of the name of your attribute

Comment: @Guyb you are welcome , can you mark it as an answer